# I want reposition/reorganize a set of data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have set of data, in xlsx format, an example in (pic1), that I want to reposition/reorganize as in (pic2). Is there a formula that can help me achieve this?

#### Original data

[image: Original data]

#### How it should be reorganized

[image: How it should be reorganized]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Power Query` (*available in Excel 2010+, although you may need to download and install MS free add-in for Excel 2010-2013*):

- Pivot columns

  - Select Column 2
  - Values Column:  Column 1
  - Advanced Options:  Don't Aggregate

[image]

Then just select all the columns in the Power Query Editor, and Replace `null` with `0`

[image]

If you must use a formula, with the layout setup as below, you can enter the **array** formula:

```
G9:  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(($F9=$A$2:$A$7)*(G$8=$C$2:$C$7))*ROW($B$1:$B$6),{1,2,3,4,5,6})),"0")
```

and fill right and down to populate the remaining cells in the Output.

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

I think the `PQ` method will be easier to update if your table size changes, although you can use Tables and/or dynamic ranges to make the formula method function in a similar fashion.